# Ordering objects by users reviews criteria

Tags: algorithm, average, leaderboard

I developed an application where users can vote objects with stars from one to five.

Then these objects are ordered in the list by votes average discarding objects with less than X votes.

Let's assume X = 10.
A object having 4.9 as average and 2k votes is under an object having 5.0 average and 10 votes.
It is right indeed, but not very beautiful and correct I think. Is there a better way to order objects?

Ordering by amount of votes not considering the average is very bad so I didn't do it.

Comment: you can assign a weight to the number of votes and to the average, depending on how much importance do you want them to have respectively

Comment: @Alessio thank you! Could you please write an example of the formula you would use? Just to be sure I understood your thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to take the lower bound of a statistical confidence interval for the average score. Then having few votes tends to depress the score, because the confidence interval is wide. See https://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html